# What are the enmity modifiers for Unleash and Abyssal Drain, post-Stormblood?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

With the release of Stormblood, the potencies and enmity modifiers for a Dark Knight's Unleash and Abyssal Drain were modified.

Unleash has the [effect](http://xivdb.com/action/3621/unleash):

> Deals unaspected damage with a potency of 50 to all nearby enemies.
>   Additional Effect: Increased enmity

Abyssal Drain [says the following](http://xivdb.com/action/3641/abyssal+drain):

> Deals unaspected damage with a potency of 120 to target and all enemies nearby it.
>   Additional Effect: Increased enmity

But what is the difference in "increased enmity" between the two abilities?

From a pure damage perspective, [Abyssal Drain seems to be the better choice](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/6jdhq9/dark_knight_mp_efficiency_and_you/), but from a pure threat perspective, which is more powerful for generating enmity?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if there are emity differences between the two skills however I do know the big difference between the two now is that damage and how the skill actually attacks the target. I would add that as an answer but it doesn't fit your question since I do not know if the modifiers are out in the open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incorrect data as of version 4.01 patch**

As of Stormblood patch 4.0 there is a major difference in enmity generated from Abyssal Drain and Unleash.

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/wiki/enmity) Unleash generates 515 enmity when you use it and Abyssal Drain generates 600 enmity per use. So Abyssal Drain trumps Unleash when generating enmity, so that brings up the question.

**When should I use Unleash over Abyssal Drain then?**

One major factor to take into consideration when deciding what enmity booster to use for AOEs you need to pay attention to how the skill works. Unleash is a slightly weaker AOE and generates less enmity than Abyssal Drain, however the skill is targeted **around you** and requires no target where as Abyssal Drain **requires a target and is based around the target, not you**. This trait of

Unleash is helpful for starting off group battles or when the enemies are surrounding you. Abyssal Drain targets an enemy and performs the AOE **around the enemy** so if you are surrounded by enemies Abyssal Drain may miss enemies around you. Once you get the enemies you're fighting grouped up properly Abyssal Drain is your best bet for generating enmity.

Another thing to take note of is the MP costs of the skills, Abyssal Drain costs more MP to use than Unleash does, so if you are hurting for MP at the time it may be beneficial to use Unleash over Abyssal Drain and take the small hit to damage and enmity generation.

**Patch 4.01 updated answer**

As of the 4.01 Omega patch the modifiers for Unleash and Abyssal Drain have been modified again. In this patch Unleash now has a 20.6x modifier giving a enmity potency of 1030 whereas Abyssal Drain remains with a 5x potency giving 600 enmity. With this update Unleash is the more powerful enmity generating AOE attack for the Dark Knight. It is still important to remember how the skill is used and Abyssal Drain still does more damage but Unleash is now the most potent skill for Dark Knights to use to draw aggro from enemies.

Comment: That's an interesting link.  Though if those numbers are right, Unleash always generates _less_ enmity than Abyssal Drain (515 vs 600) whereas in Heavensward I think they were both even.

Comment: @Troyen yeah looking over it now, Abyssal Drain does always generate more than Unleash does. However the way the skill attacks the target is still something that is helpful to know on when to use Unleash since it is a good starter since enemies won't usually group up nicely for you to target them and use Abyssal Drain on them. I'll edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Looks like 4.01 is tweaking the enmity modifier for Unleash again, so when the new numbers are figured out you may want to update your answer.

Comment: @Troyen updated the answer with 4.01 information, looks like Unleash is good again for Dark Knight.